# Discordgo Modal Error (Union Type Choices)

Tags: go, discord, bots

I am trying to make a Modal where you can enter Host, Port, Method and start a Connection to that Server.

I am getting this Error tho:
I dont quite now where I am missing something since I defined the Type to be StringSelectMenu.

`HTTP 400 Bad Request, {"code": 50035, "errors": {"data": {"components": {"3": {"components": {"0": {"_errors": [{"code": "UNION_TYPE_CHOICES", "message": "Value of field "type" must be one of (4,)."}]}}}}}}, "message": "Invalid Form Body"}`

The Code:

````
 err := s.InteractionRespond(i.Interaction, &discordgo.InteractionResponse{
        Type: discordgo.InteractionResponseModal,
        Data: &discordgo.InteractionResponseData{
            CustomID: "ssh_screen_" + i.Interaction.Member.User.ID,
            Title:    "Preparing SSH Access",
            Components: []discordgo.MessageComponent{
                discordgo.ActionsRow{
                    Components: []discordgo.MessageComponent{
                        discordgo.TextInput{
                            CustomID:    "Host",
                            Label:       "Host",
                            Style:       discordgo.TextInputShort,
                            Placeholder: "e.g 127.0.1",
                            Required:    true,
                            MaxLength:   300,
                            MinLength:   4,
                        },
                    },
                },
                discordgo.ActionsRow{
                    Components: []discordgo.MessageComponent{
                        discordgo.TextInput{
                            CustomID:    "Port",
                            Label:       "Port",
                            Placeholder: "e.g 80",
                            Style:       discordgo.TextInputShort,
                            Required:    true,
                            MinLength:   1,
                            MaxLength:   5,
                        },
                    },
                },
                discordgo.ActionsRow{
                    Components: []discordgo.MessageComponent{
                        discordgo.SelectMenu{
                            MenuType:    discordgo.StringSelectMenu,
                            CustomID:    "Method",
                            Placeholder: "Select a method",
                            Options: []discordgo.SelectMenuOption{
                                {
                                    Label:       "SSH",
                                    Description: "SSH Protocol to connect",
                                    Value:       "SSH",
                                    Default:     true,
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
    ```


EDIT:
The Solution is to Delete the SelectMenu since its not supported in Modals
````